# How to use the session in Next.js handler?

Tags: next.js, websocket

I am trying to implement a websocket server inside my Next.js app:

```js
import { Server, Socket } from 'socket.io'
import { txsDisplay } from '../worker-callback/route';
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react';

// Compare to https://clouddevs.com/next/socketio-and-websocket-api/
const handler = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const session = useSession();
  const email = session.data?.user?.email;
  if (email === undefined) {
      return;
  }

  if ((res as any).socket.server.io) {
    console.log('Socket is already running');
  } else {
    console.log('Socket is initializing');
    const io = new Server((res as any).socket.server);
    (res as any).socket.server.io = io;
    io.on('connection', (socket: Socket) => {
      txsDisplay.addWebSocket(socket, email!); // FIXME: `!`
    });
  }
  (res as any).end();
}

export default handler;
```

How to work around the following error:

```
React Hook "useSession" is called in function "handler" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use".eslintreact-hooks/rules-of-hooks`
```

Comment: That's a _linting_ error. But also is exactly the problem it says it is: you can't use React hooks outside of React components.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know this. My question is not _why_ it does not work, but how to make it work.

Comment: You are using a hook in something that is not a component, my guess is that you should pass the session as a parameter of the function from the component you are calling the handler(). Hooks should always be associated with a component

Comment: Did you read e.g. https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/initialization#route-handlers-app

Comment: Yep, in next-auth.js.org the code it's a component, not a const handler, change the code and create it as a function export default function(). But I think you really should consider the structure, a handler should not be a component, but something to be called inside one.

Comment: @jonrsharpe @ByteVictor The compiler requires me to add `providers`. Should I add the same providers as what I have in `app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts`?

Comment: @ByteVictor Where to add `useSession()` in NextAuth code? I can't add it into `NextAuth` component, because it **not** a function ` function NextAuth(...)`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I also don't understand the syntax (is `session` a function?):
```
    callbacks: {
      session({ session, token }) {
```

Comment: This is just basic JS syntax, it's a callback [_method_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I tried to follow your advice, but met the next obstacle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77978311/argument-type-for-get-and-for-nextauth

Answer (score 0):

It works by replacing `useSession()` by `await getServerSession()`.

Also I replaced the next line by

```js
const email = session?.user?.email;
```