# Argument type for `GET` and for `NextAuth`

Tags: next.js, next-auth

In the following Next.js code (`main/app/api/txs-socket/route.ts`) argument types don't match for `GET` and `NextAuth`. How to correct this code to make it work?

```
[0] app/api/txs-socket/route.ts
[0] Type error: Route "app/api/txs-socket/route.ts" has an invalid "GET" export:
[0]   Type "NextApiRequest" is not a valid type for the function's first argument.
[0]     Expected "Request | NextRequest", got "NextApiRequest".
```

```js
import { Server, Socket } from 'socket.io'
import { txsDisplay } from '../worker-callback/route';
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google"
import config from "@/../config.json";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  // Do whatever you want here, before the request is passed down to `NextAuth`
  return await NextAuth(req, res, {
    providers: [ // FIXME: duplicate code
        GoogleProvider({
          clientId: config.GOOGLE_ID!,
          clientSecret: config.GOOGLE_SECRET!,
        }),
        // TODO: add more providers here
    ],
    callbacks: {
      session({ session, user }) {
        // ...
        return session;
      }
    }
  })
}

export { handler as GET };
```

Comment: Have you tried converting the type for the `req` to `NextRequest` or `Request`?

Comment: @MubashirWaheed Yes, I tried